# Create multiple postgres objects using Terraform and for_each meta argument

Tags: foreach, terraform

I would like to create several postgres users, databases and passwords and output them with terraform. As of now, what I'm doing is this (for one of the application database):

main.tf

```
resource "random_password" "secret_password_1" {
  length           = 16
  special          = true
  override_special = "!#$%&*()-_=+[]{}<>:?"
}

resource "postgresql_role" "application_db_role_1" {
  name               = "db_user_1"
  login              = true
  password           = random_password.secret_password_1.result
  encrypted_password = true
}

resource "postgresql_database" "application_db_1" {
  name               = "db_name_1"
  owner             = postgresql_role.application_db_role_1.name
  allow_connections = true
}
```

outputs.tf

```
output "db_name_1" {
  value = postgresql_database.application_db_1.name
}

output "db_user_1" {
  value = postgresql_role.application_db_role_1.name
}

output "db_1_password" {
  value     = random_password.secret_password_1.result
  sensitive = true
}
```

Would it be possible to use for_each meta argument to make this code simpler when having several databases, starting from a list of DB names such as:

```
locals {
  list_of_databases = ["db_1", "db_2"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a clean solution:

main.tf

```
locals {
  list_of_databases = ["one_database_example"]
}

resource "random_password" "password" {
  for_each         = toset(local.list_of_databases)
  length           = 16
  special          = true
  override_special = "!#$%&*()-_=+[]{}<>:?"
}

resource "postgresql_role" "application_db_role" {
  for_each           = toset(local.list_of_databases)
  name               = "${each.value}_user"
  login              = true
  password           = random_password.password[each.value].result
  encrypted_password = true
}

resource "postgresql_database" "application_db" {
  for_each          = toset(local.list_of_databases)
  name              = "${each.value}_db"
  owner             = postgresql_role.application_db_role[each.value].name
  allow_connections = true
}
```

And outputs

```
output "shared_db_application_db_names" {
  value = {
    for v in local.list_of_databases : v => postgresql_database.application_db[v].name
  }
}

output "shared_db_application_db_roles" {
  value = {
    for v in local.list_of_databases : v => postgresql_role.application_db_role[v].name
  }
}

output "shared_db_application_db_passwords" {
  value = {
    for v in local.list_of_databases : v => random_password.password[v].result
  }
  sensitive = true
}
```